# How can I merge the columns (list) in a spark dataframe into groups?

Tags: api, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to combine a list based on a date in a data frame where the column is a list.How can I do this?

[image]

example

```
Date           words      

2020-07-26    ["hello", "world"]      

2020-07-26    ["hello", "Stack Overflow"]
```

---

result

```
Date           words

2020-07-26    ["hello","world","hello","Stack Overflow"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy`, `flatten` & `collect_list` functions.

Check below code.

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-----------------------+
|date      |words                  |
+----------+-----------------------+
|2020-07-26|[hello, world]         |
|2020-07-26|[hello, Stack Overflow]|
+----------+-----------------------+
```

```
df \
.groupBy("date") \
.agg(flatten(collect_list(col("words")).alias("words"))
.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-------------------------------------+
|date      |words                                |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
|2020-07-26|[hello, world, hello, Stack Overflow]|
+----------+-------------------------------------+
```